# Trying to load variables into the database and it is not succeeding

Tags: php, mysqli, insert

I have this small section of code which is loading variables into a database table.

As you can see `$insertResult` is not output so it fails in the if statement where if all went as planned it would not:

[image]

It should query the table with `$topInsert` and load the variables into the table topics.

```
$topName = $_POST['topName'];
                $topCat = $_POST['topCat'];
                $loggedUser = $_SESSION['loggedUser'];

                echo $topCat;

                $userID = "SELECT ID FROM users WHERE username = '$loggedUser'";
                $getID = mysqli_query($connect, $userID);
                $rowID = mysqli_fetch_array($getID);
                $userID = $rowID['ID'];
                echo $userID;
                $topInsert = "INSERT INTO topics(topicSubject, topicDate, topicCat, topicBy) VALUES('$topName', NULL, '$topCat', '$userID')";
                $insertResult = mysqli_query($connect, $topInsert);


                if(!$insertResult){

                    echo "<p style='margin-top: 75px;'>Error: Data could not be loaded to the database. Please try again.</p>";
                    $sqlRoll = "ROLLBACK;";
                    $rollResult = mysqli_query($connect, $sqlRoll);
                }
```

By this point I am pretty sure that all of the data types in the table correspond correctly with what I am trying to enter but cannot figure out what is not working correctly.

I have struggled with this since yesterday and have decided I need some help pinpointing which bit of code is failing.

Please feel free to ask for more information to be posted in case I have missed anything.

I appreciate any replies.

Comment: You need to add error handling, either by having mysqli throw exceptions or by checking the error messages after your operations directly.

Comment: The beauty of this API is that it affords the use of parametrised queries. Use th m!!

Comment: Are you not violating the type variables? You didn't show us the $topName, $topCat, $userID and since topCat and topBy fields are int maybe you are trying to assign a String to an int field.

Comment: This is where I apologise for the confusing variable names. `$topCat` is topicCat in the table and is the category ID from the categories table which is an integer. `$userID` is the user ID from the users table and is also an integer. I probably should have included a bit more code in the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set topicDate column to allow NULL Values in PHPADMIN or don't put NULL in the query

Comment: Thank you, this fixed it. Once I changed this it went straight to the next statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out.

```
$topName = $_POST['topName'];
$topCat = $_POST['topCat'];
$loggedUser = $_SESSION['loggedUser'];
echo $topCat;

//check if connection to database is succesfull first, then

$result = "SELECT ID FROM users WHERE username = '$loggedUser'";
if($result->num_rows >0){

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
  $userID = $row["ID"];

}
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO topics(topicSubject, topicDate, topicCat, topicBy) VALUES('$topName', NULL, '$topCat', '$userID')";


    if(mysqli_query($con, $sql)){
        echo "Succesfully added"."<br>";
    }
    else{
        echo "Data could not be loaded"."<br>";

    }

    mysqli_close($connect);
```

Comment: for me the line `if*$result->num_rows >0)` comes back as **Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\phpSiteTest\topCreate.php on line 183**

Comment: Have you tried to execute the SELECT statement on the mysql sql command line and see if it returns any results?

Comment: @ixxCarbonxZZ Give us:
`$result = "SELECT ID FROM users WHERE username = #loggedUser'"; print_r($result)`

Comment: `SELECT ID FROM users WHERE username = 'Admin'` was the output of `print_r($result)`